# Node : Error in Updating Data: user.update : Returns null

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

when i use user.update query it updates none of the user.
it returns null .
i want to push `Array` in my existing Record

#### Model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

var schema = new Schema({
    email: { type: String, require: true },
    username: { type: String, require: true },
    password: { type: String, require: true },
    creation_dt: { type: String, require: true },
    tasks:[{type:{type:String}}]
},

);
module.exports = mongoose.model('User',schema)
```

This is the `Model` i'm using and I want to push some data in `tasks[]`

#### Code :

```
router.post('/newTask', function (req, res, next) {
  var dataa = {
    pName: req.body.pName,
    pTitle: req.body.pTitle,
    pStartTime: req.body.pStartTime,
    pEndTime: req.body.pEndTime,
    pSessionTime: req.body.pSessionTime
  }

  var usr = new User(req.user)
  usr.update(
    {_id:req.user._id},
    {$push:{tasks:dataa}}
  )
  console.log(usr)
  try {
    doc = usr.save();
    return res.status(201).json(doc);
  }
  catch (err) {
    return res.status(501).json(err);
  }
})
```

`_id:req.user.id` returns the exiting id and i want to push data in that used which user is going to post and show user specific data

#### Output:

[image: Output]
Can someone Solve this Problem?? 
at last I want user specific data I tried a lot with more and more twist but sometimes it `update` same record for 2 times sometimes it updates nothing I don't know what I can do next.

Thank You

Comment: send `JSON` file

Comment: If this `tasks:[{type:{type:String}}]` is what you actualy have as a definition of the tasks then it will not work. It should be more like this `tasks:[{ pName: {type:String}, pTitle: {type:String}, ....}]`

Comment: Also with `new User(...)` you create new user so using update before you even save it to db doesn't make any sense. If the user exists you should use `User.update({ _id: req.user._id }, { $push: { tasks: dataa }}).exec(function(err, result){ ... })`

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues.

1, `user.save()` is async, so you have to `await` it's return if you want to use `doc`.

2, you are creating a new `User` instead of updating a `User` that already exists.

This code fixes both issues:

```
router.post('/newTask', async function (req, res, next) {

  var data = {
    pName: req.body.pName,
    pTitle: req.body.pTitle,
    pStartTime: req.body.pStartTime,
    pEndTime: req.body.pEndTime,
    pSessionTime: req.body.pSessionTime
  }

  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.user.id);
    user.tasks.push(data);
    const doc = await user.save();
    return res.status(200).json(doc);
  }
  catch (err) {
    return res.status(501).json(err);
  }

});
```